# Is it good to submit our site in website submission sites?

Tags: seo, search-engines, web-crawlers, links, backlinks

I was wondering why don't we submit our site in website submission sites and increase our site's rank.
Is is good to do this? How is this working?
 Is this a spam activity?
  What are the advantages and disadvantages of doing this?

Comment: Absolutely not! Many of these will submit your site to places you should not. This especially includes directory sites which are mostly seen as trash in Googles eyes these days. Do not be indiscriminate in how you handle your site. Please. Cheers!!

Answer (score 3):

It won't help you with you ranking. Don't make your backlink portoflio dirty. Any website that offers website submissions should be a red flag for you already. Attract links organically by having a great design and content. No need to get useless links from some submission sites. Eventually they will hurt your ranking, not increase.

Answer (score 1):

Getting listed in link directories was a good SEO strategy 15 years ago.  However, any advice that you do so today is outdated.

These days it is more likely to get your site penalized.   Google views most link directories as low quality sites.   If you have to pay to get your link into the directory then Google would consider the link paid and "unnatural".

Answer (score 0):

It is good idea to submit it to submission websites but only that condition if the content is relevant to directory and second thing is check the submission directory reputation .